# Static files not being served for one particular controller

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an app using Devise for authentication. I have some custom stylesheets in the `public` directory.

I set `config.serve_static_files = true` in `development.rb`.

The assets are being served properly for every other controller except `devise/passwords` controller.

For the passwords I am getting a No route matches error.

Login page: http://www.pharma4doc.in/login  (working properly)

Forgot password page: http://www.pharma4doc.in/password/new  (CSS files not being served)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you add /password/ to assets path for password page - http://www.pharma4doc.in/password/assets/stylesheets/styles-login.css somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [asset url helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-stylesheet_path) in your templates. It will ensure the path to the static assets is correct all the time.